# websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, websocket

I am trying to communicate with Flask websocket from a python script. But I am getting the following exception.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 5, in <module>
    socket = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:5000")
  File "C:\Users\anyms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 514, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "C:\Users\anyms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 226, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "C:\Users\anyms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 79, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "C:\Users\anyms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 160, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d %s", status, status_message, resp_headers)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 404 NOT FOUND
```

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "uhjsbajksHGhksajjf^&*8*()"
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@socketio.on("message")
def message(msg):
    print("Message received: {}".format(msg))
    send(msg, broadcast=True)


@socketio.on("connect")
def connect():
    print("Connected!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

**client.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from websocket import create_connection

socket = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:5000")
socket.send("hello, world")

result = socket.recv()
print("Received: {}".format(result))

socket.close()
```

If I write an HTML page as a client it works fine, but I could not connect from my python script.

When I use `ws://echo.websocket.org` it works fine, I am confused, I am new to websocket programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 year old now, but basically websockets and socket.io are two different methods of creating a socket. They are not compatible. You have a socket.io server but a websocket client. Change either one to match the other and it should work.